# Vertical line separating the fringe and the buffer

Tags: emacs, graphics, line, fringe

Is there a way to get a vertical line between the fringe and the buffer, such as in http://manual.macromates.com/en/navigation_overview#collapsing_text_blocks_foldings?

**EDIT --** See http://screencast.com/t/rpY9abzQK for the 1-px wide separation line I'd like to have **between** the 8-px fringe and the buffer itself. I hope it's clearer now...

Comment: The fringe can have a certain color like:  `(set-face-attribute 'fringe nil :background "black")`  The fringe can have a certain width like:  `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(left-fringe . 11))` or `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(right-fringe . 0))`  Whereas the prior two settings affect every window in the frame, it is possible to control fringes on a per-window basis -- e.g., `(setq left-fringe-width 10)` and `(setq right-fringe-width 0)`  Or, those window settings can be made a default with `setq-default`.

Comment: @lawlist -- Thanks for your input. Though, it isn't what I was looking for. Is my request clear now?

Comment: I only know how to do that with an overlay before-string, but it's not very efficient and would need to be redrawn after every change of the buffer, and a decision would need to be made regarding whether it only covers the visible window, or the entire buffer -- e.g., some people use things like follow-mode that shows more than just 50 lines of text.  There would also be a potential conflict with minor modes that use before-string overlays -- e.g., linum-mode, nlinum-mode, etc.  Let's first see whether someone else has a better idea for you.

Comment: @user3341592 I do not think that this is easily possible.

Comment: You can perhaps fiddle with display margins, displaying whatever you want in a margin - see [(elisp) `Display Margins`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Margins.html#Display-Margins). Other than that, no, I don't think there is anything available for this. There is no frame parameter for it, for example.